# Bluetooth suddenly stops working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, bluetooth

I'm running Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon on a [Gigabyte Brix GB-BKi3HA-7100](https://www.gigabyte.com/Mini-PcBarebone/GB-BKi3HA-7100-rev-10#ov).  Surprisingly, Bluetooth worked *perfectly* out-of-the box.  I was able to simply click the Bluetooth icon in the task bar, it scanned for devices, found my device, paired and connected with minimal fuss.

This amazing state of affairs lasted for about 2 weeks.  Suddenly, I was having trouble pairing with a device.  I rebooted the computer, and suddenly Bluetooth seemed to stop working entirely.  When scanning for devices it would never list a single device, whereas before it would list over ten devices it found in the local area (I live in an apartment building so it usually will pick up at least 10-15 devices from my neighbors).

So, on to debugging.  The output of `rfkill list all` shows:

```
# rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
398: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

... so it appears the bluetooth adaptor at least still exists and is not blocked.

I can explicitly start and enable the bluetooth service:

```
# systemctl start bluetooth.service
# systemctl enable bluetooth.service
    Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
    Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
```

But if I try to explictly bring the `hci0` device up, it fails:

```
# hciconfig hci0 up
Can't get device info: No such device
```

More strangely, neither `lspci` nor `lsusb` even show any Bluetooth adaptor on the system:

```
# lspci | grep -i blue
# lsusb | grep -i blue
```

... but I'm sure the Gigabyte Brix has a bluetooth adaptor because, well, it was working for 2 weeks, and the `hci0` bluetooth interface shows up in `rfkill list all`.

And the service seems to be running fine:

```
# service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-09-29 12:05:21 EDT; 1h 38min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 743 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─743 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 29 12:05:21 XXX-GB-BKi3-H-A-7100 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 29 12:05:21 XXX-GB-BKi3-H-A-7100 bluetoothd[743]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Sep 29 12:05:21 XXX-GB-BKi3-H-A-7100 bluetoothd[743]: Starting SDP server
Sep 29 12:05:21 XXX-GB-BKi3-H-A-7100 bluetoothd[743]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Sep 29 12:05:21 XXX-GB-BKi3-H-A-7100 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

When I try using `bluetoothctl show` I get the error message `No default controller available`.

```
# bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

So what are some possible causes of this?  One the one hand, `lspci` and `lsusb` don't show a bluetooth adaptor, which seems very alarming.  But `rfkill list all` shows the `hci0` bluetooth interface, and the bluetooth service itself seems to be running.

But ultimately I can't actually even scan for devices.  What could be happening here?  The symptoms look like the software service is working, but it's as if the computer has no actual hardware bluetooth adaptor (except I know it does because it was working for 2 weeks perfectly.)